# Spray: Testing File Uploads with Specs2

Tags: spray, specs2

I have an API built using Spray that handles file uploads.
I am trying to write a test for the upload functionality but I'm not getting anywhere fast. I'm nots sure how to structure the test to simulate a file upload.
I have the following test...

```
"Valid POST Requests should return success" in {
  Post("/upload", HttpEntity(MediaTypes.`multipart/form-data`, """{"filename":"a.wav"}""")) ~> 
  sealRoute(uploadRoute) ~> check {
    response.status should be equalTo OK
    responseAs[String] === "..."
  }
}
```

Running this produces the following error message...

```
Content-Type with a multipart media type must have a non-empty 'boundary' parameter' is not equal to ...
```

This seems like an error message similar to how to mock POST/Upload requests using apache bench where you have to specify a post file and the boundary to separate the form items.
I was hoping for something closer to how CURL works.

Either way, can anyone point me in the right direction as to how I correctly structure such a test?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I managed to get this working by cobbling together some code from a variety of posts I found - primarily posts relating to using spray-client to do file uploads.
Probably not the prettiest but works for me! :)

```
"Valid POST Requests should return success" in {
  val file = new File("a.wav")
  val httpEntity = HttpEntity(MediaTypes.`multipart/form-data`, HttpData(file)).asInstanceOf[HttpEntity.NonEmpty]
  val formFile = FormFile("file", httpEntity)
  val mfd = MultipartFormData(Seq(BodyPart(formFile, "file")))
  Post("/upload", mfd) ~> sealRoute(uploadRoute) ~> check {
    response.status should be equalTo OK
    body.contentType.toString() === "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    responseAs[String] === "Success!"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, or question.

Try adding a boundary by doing:

Post("/upload", HttpEntity(MediaTypes.`multipart/form-data`.withBoundary("-somerandomboundary"), """{"filename":"a.wav"}""")) ~>

Although, you might face the next bump I face, which is an error saying it requires a start boundary.

Comment: Hi, I tried that as I had seen issues before but like you said just ran into another issue. Anyway, I actually just got this working (for me anyway!) and will post my solution as an answer